# Some questions about Calculating "street_length_avg" in Linzhi City, Xizang, China

Tags: python, osmnx

I tried to download shapefiles of some cities and calculate their 'street_length_avg' by OSMnx, but found some error about nodes of  Linzhi City, Xizang, China:

[image: Road network 1 of Linzhi City, Xizang, China] 
[image: Road network 2 of Linzhi City, Xizang, China]

As shown in figures，I found that nodes on a long road have not been properly simplified，which will lead to the incorrect calculations of ‘street_length_avg’(46.62, less than any city in China)

[image: Statistical data of Linzhi City, Xizang, China]

But at the same time, the calculated value of the road network (like Shanghai，China) with more intersections is normal.

[image: Statistical data of Shanghai，China]

Is there something wrong with my operation? Here are my code:

```
G6 = ox.graph_from_place('Linzhi City, Xizang, China')
ox.save_graphml(G6, filename=("林芝市" + '.graphml'), folder="F:/python_code/data/", gephi=False)
ox.save_graph_shapefile(G6, filename=("林芝市" + '.shp'), 
folder="F:/python_code/data/cityshapefile/")
stats =ox.basic_stats(G6)
print(str(stats['street_length_avg']))
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G6)
```

Comment: I'm getting a very [different graph](https://imgur.com/a/eonqGRd) than you did when I run your code, so it's tough to troubleshoot exactly what you were seeing.

Comment: If you can reproduce this issue, please open an issue in the OSMnx Github repo: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues